# Rectangle curved ends (not rounded corners)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Help! In Illustrator how can I curve the ends of a rectangle very slightly so it follows the same path as the circle background it is sitting on? I don't want rounded corners of a rectangle, just the end of the rectangle to be slightly curved. I feel like this should be so easy and yet I am having trouble with it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi GeorgeW, Welcome to GD.SE! This is a little hard to visualize and a picture could help but my guess would be to just add an anchor point at the end and move it out a bit and convert the anchor point to smooth.

Comment: If what I visualize in my head is what you do too, then you'll probably want to use Andrew's method or an Envelope Distort.  You should really post a pic though, as Andrew said.  We are a visual community...

Comment: Thank you! I added several anchor points to each end and pulled them out and I think it worked okay. I didnt smooth it but when I dragged the points out it seemed to align with the background circle. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try adding a stroke an select the round corner?

//ignore the stroke weight 
[image]

Or, if you have the last version of illustrator, select the shape with the direct selection tool (press "a" on your keyboard), and move the white dots.

[image]